# Limit of a multivariable piecewise function

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by:
>
> $f(x,y) =
>   \begin{cases} 
>       x-y+1     & \text{if }xy\geq 0 \\
>       y-x-1  & \text{if } xy<0 \\
>   \end{cases}$

I need to compute $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}f(x,y)$, but I'm not sure about the following reasoning:

The problem here is that $f$, close to $(0,1)$, corresponds to different formulas.

If $D_1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: xy\geq0\}$ and $D_2=(D_1)^C$, we have

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1),(x,y)\in D_1}f(x,y)=0$ and the same for $(x,y)\in D_2$, because $f$ is continuous on $D_1$ and $D_2$. So, can I conclude that the limit is $0$?

My english isn't very good; if you find any errors, please correct them.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done seems generally okay, yes, except for one minor point: the fact that $f$ is continuous on $D_{2}$ is irrelevant since $(0,1)\not\in D_{2}$. What you mean to say is that you've simply evaluated the limit using the expression that gives the values that $f$ takes on $D_{2}$, which should be perfectly acceptable here.

The following hint is intended to provide a slicker method.

**Hint:** notice that $x-y+1=-(y-x-1)$. Now, evaluate the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)}\lvert f(x,y) \rvert$. What can you conclude?

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks. But anyway, the argument used in my proof (about $D_1$ and $D_2$) is correct?

Comment: About your edit: 
You're right, so, how can I justify that the limit is $0$ on $D_2$?

Comment: I would accept your argument as 'convincing enough'. As for justifying that the limit is $0$ on $D_{2}$, the brute force approach is to let $\epsilon>0$ and show that there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $(x,y)\in D_{2}\cap B((0,1),\delta)$ then $\lvert f(x,y)-0\rvert<\epsilon$. Alternatively, an argument using sequences could probably be constructed (which would be equivalent, of course). But I'm pretty sure most people would accept something like "the function $g(x,y)=y-x-1$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, so $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,1)} f(x,y) =\ldots$" etc.

Comment: To summarize my last comment: justifying that the limit is $0$ on $D_{2}$ is not hard, because there's nothing wrong with saying "$f$ takes *these* values on $D_{2}$, so the limit is *this*". The reason why there's nothing wrong with this is because, if you really wanted to, you could actually use the definition of the limit, at which point you would inevitably plug in the relevant expression for $f(x,y)$ anyway.